# Can glsl be used instead of webgl?

Tags: javascript, 3d, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

This may be a bit of a naive question so please go easy on me. But I was looking at shaders at [shadertoy.com](http://shadertoy.com) and I'm amazed at how small the glsl code is for the 3d scenes. Digging deeper I noticed how most of the shaders use a technique called [ray marching](http://jamie-wong.com/2016/07/15/ray-marching-signed-distance-functions/).

This technique makes it possible to avoid using vertices/triangles altogether and just employ the pixel shader and some math to create some pretty complex scenes.

So I was wondering why is it that 3d scenes often use triangle meshes with webgl instead of just using pixel shaders. Can't we just render the entire scene with glsl and pixel shaders (aka fragment shaders)?

Comment: BTW: There is no `glBegin/glEnd` in WebGL and for that matter it's been long deprecated in OpenGL as well. If you want to learn WebGL might I suggest [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: @gman ok edited, I meant whatever current way they draw vertices.

Comment: Check a game called Marble Marcher, so in theory you could use a pixel shader instead of the regural pipeline, but as gman said, its more computationally expensive as you are computing for example a fractal and then rendering it, so you trade dynamism (being able to modify things like light positions, that are generally baked instead of computed at real time, or parameters of a fractal) for performance.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez thanks that's a good resource. I believe that gpus will just get faster and faster so raytracing/raymarching in the future will get more widely adopted.

Comment: What is happening now is that they are building specialized cores just for that haven't you seen the RT cores on the new RTX's from nVidia?

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez yes I saw rtx, but my understanding is that games will still use triangulation in their pipeline. I'm not quite sure how rtx is going to help raymarching. I'm primarily interested in creating everything procedurally so no models.

Comment: You could model procedurally the vertices to take advantage of the new and old pipelines, by the way if you don't want to change your geometry in real-time you are better off modeling in a tool like Houdini or Rhino/Grasshopper that enables proceduralism and importing your results to the pipeline, if you do want interactivity you can model in your vertex shader directly. It all comes down to what you want to do and at what cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is because the techniques on shadertoy are probably 10,100,1000 times slower than using vertices and triangles.

Compare this shadertoy forest that runs at 1fps at best fullscreen on my laptop

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4ttSWf

To this Skyrim forest which runs at 30 to 60fps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjqsYzBrP-M

Compare this Shadertoy city which runs at 5fps on my laptop

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XtsSWs

To this Cities:Skylines city which runs at 60fps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gI2N10QyRA

Compare this Shadertoy Journey clone which runs 1fps fullscreen on my laptop

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldlcRf

to the actual Journey game on PS3, a machine with an arguably slower GPU than my laptop given the PS3 came out in 2006, and yet runs at 60fps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61DZC-60x20#t=0m46s

There's plenty of other reasons. A typical 3D world uses gigabytes of data for textures, characters, animations, collisions etc, none of that is available in just GLSL. Another is often they use fractal techniques so there's no easy way to actually *design* anything. Instead they just search the math for something interesting. That would not be a good way to design game levels for example. In other words using data of vertices makes things far more flexible and editable.

Compare the Journey examples above. The Shadertoy example is a single scene vs the game which is a vast designed world with buildings and ruins and puzzles etc...

There's a reason it's called Shader**TOY**. It's a meant as a fun challenge. Given a single function who's only input is which pixel is currently being drawn, write code to draw something. As such the images people have managed to draw given that limit are amazing!

But, they aren't *generally* the techniques used to write real apps. If you want your app to run fast and be flexible you use the more traditional techniques of vertices and triangles. The techniques used by GTA5, Red Dead Redemption 2, Call of Duty, Apex Legends, Fortnite, etc....

Comment: but demoscene 4kb demos seem to use raymarching and their demos are blazing.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roZ-Cgxe9bU

Comment: First off the demo you linked to is pretty undetailed. Second many 4k demos require top end GPUs to run at a reasonable framerate and still do almost nothing. They pick one technique and just repeat it for 1-2 minutes.

Comment: hmm, how about for data visualizations then?

Comment: It depends on the visualization. Most things you want to visualize require data. More often than not the way you'd likely want to visualize that data doesn't work well with a single fragment shader. And, even if you could do it with a single fragment shader it would likely require extremely complicated math and be inflexible vs doing the more traditional ways which are simpler and flexible.

Comment: I'm still drawn to it. the code just seems so nice and small. also, I like how it resembles ray tracing so it's more like the physical world. and I like that as a programmer I don't need models and I don't need to mess with vertices/triangles. there's just alot of things to like about this.

Comment: Do whatever you want. I'm not telling you not to do it. You asked why people don't do it more. I gave you the answer. vertices and triangles are faster and more flexible but you're free to do whatever you want. It's fun to make shadertoy style shaders even if they are inflexible and slow. I enjoy making [the vertex shader equivalent](https://vertexshaderart.com) because it's fun