# What exactly does this calculation mean?

Tags: math, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm new to GLSL and learning from the tutorial here.
(It's using ShaderToy)

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-coding-graphics-shaders--cms-23313

My question is why you can set x coordinates to 0-1 by dividing the fragCoord's x coordinates by the iResolution(screensize).

It might be just a math question, but I'm confused what exactly the "iResolution.x" indicates or what kind of calculation is made here. (Is it a vector division? )

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 xy = fragCoord.xy; //We obtain our coordinates for the current pixel
    xy.x = xy.x / iResolution.x; //We divide the coordinates by the screen size
    xy.y = xy.y / iResolution.y;
    // Now x is 0 for the leftmost pixel, and 1 for the rightmost pixel
    vec4 solidRed = vec4(0,0.0,0.0,1.0); //This is actually black right now
    if(xy.x > 0.5){
        solidRed.r = 1.0; //Set its red component to 1.0
    }
    fragColor = solidRed;
}
```

Comment: (Probably) `fragCoord.xy` is the 2-dimensional coordinate of the fragment in pixel unit. `iResolution.xy` is the size of the viewport in pixel. `fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy` calculates the coordinate of the fragment in the range [0.0, 1.0] (separately for `x` and `y`). It follows, the all fragments with a coordinate `xy.x > 0.5` are at the right half of the viewport. Note, this can be simplified `vec2 xy = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;` `fragColor = vec4(xy.x > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: @ Rabbid76 : Isn't your comment more like an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct.  `fragCoord` is the pixel currently being drawn, `iResolution` is the size of the screen so

```
xy.x = xy.x / iResolution.x; //We divide the coordinates by the screen size
xy.y = xy.y / iResolution.y
```

Gives normalized values where xy.x goes from 0 to 1 across and xy.y goes from 0 to 1 up the screen which seems to be *exactly what the comments say*

It's important to note though that `iResolution` and `fragCoord` are user variables. In this case I'm guessing you're getting this GLSL from Shadertoy. Those variables are not part of WebGL or GLSL, they are defined by Shadertoy and so their values and meaning are defined by shadertoy.

Note that if you are new to GLSL and WebGL you might want to consider some [webgl tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org). Also see [this answer about shadertoy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798106/128511)

Comment: Thank you very much, gman for your answer. Now I totally understand. Yes, I will definitely check those links!

Answer (score 2):

`iResolution.x` is the width of your screen in pixels. Dividing the pixel x location by the total width transforms the location into a fraction of the screen width. So, if your screen is 1000 pixels wide, and your current position is x=500, `xy.x = xy.x / iResolution.x;` will convert `xy.x` to 0.500.

Comment: Bill the lizard, I am following your blog on sicp on billthelizard.com and the website appears to be down.  Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @Jodast. It looks like a DNS error between Blogger and my domain hosting company. I'll see if I can get it resolved this evening. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @Jodast Until I get those issues worked out, you can find my blog at http://billthelizard.blogspot.com

Comment: Thanks, but my school district blocked blogspot.  SICP is my compsci school project for the semester